# Getting an attempted relative import error

Tags: python

I'm following this page to write a micrservice to GET data from a SQLAlchemy model:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/

And my file structure looks like this:

[image]

I can't get past this error:

```
  File "./main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import crud, models, schemas
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Can anyone clue me in?

The file in question is located here: https://github.com/goterpsgo/ecommerce/blob/decorative_base/srv_users/main.py#L8

TIA,

- Joe

Comment: What was the `pwd` (or `cwd` ) when you run the project?

Comment: I'm trying to keep the `pwd` irrelevant. I don't want to hard code that into the script.

Comment: I have added an answer below. Please do check it out